# Vercel Deployment Error: Command "CI='' npm run build" exited with 1

Tags: github, vercel

I am developing a site for my fantasy football site. I am pulling from my GitHub repository. I tried adding an environement setting of CI = false. I might have done this incorrectly. I had an initial error of Command "npm run build" exited with 1.

The logs for the error are listed below:

```
08:27:11.719    ✓ 3 modules transformed.
08:27:11.720    [vite-plugin-svelte] Unrecognized option 'enableSourcemap'
08:27:11.720    file: /vercel/path0/.svelte-kit/build/generated/root.svelte
08:27:11.720    > Unrecognized option 'enableSourcemap'
08:27:11.723    Error: Unrecognized option 'enableSourcemap'
08:27:11.723    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:31194:19
08:27:11.723    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
08:27:11.723    at validate_options (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:31188:26)
08:27:11.723    at compile (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:31232:5)
08:27:11.723    at compileSvelte2 (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:313:20)
08:27:11.724    at async Object.transform (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:1460:27)
08:27:11.759    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
08:27:11.759    npm ERR! errno 1
08:27:11.765    npm ERR! league-page@1.2.6 build: `svelte-kit build`
08:27:11.765    npm ERR! Exit status 1
08:27:11.765    npm ERR!
08:27:11.765    npm ERR! Failed at the league-page@1.2.6 build script.
08:27:11.765    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
08:27:11.776    
08:27:11.776    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
08:27:11.777    npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-11-11T14_27_11_766Z-debug.log
08:27:11.792    Error: Command "CI='' npm run build" exited with 1
```

Update:
I figured out where the Error: Command "CI='' npm run build" exited with 1 was coming from and fixed that. The initial error as I listed came back up

```
08:32:34.030    [vite-plugin-svelte] Unrecognized option 'enableSourcemap'
08:32:34.030    file: /vercel/path0/.svelte-kit/build/generated/root.svelte
08:32:34.031    > Unrecognized option 'enableSourcemap'
08:32:34.033    Error: Unrecognized option 'enableSourcemap'
08:32:34.033    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:31194:19
08:32:34.033    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
08:32:34.033    at validate_options (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:31188:26)
08:32:34.033    at compile (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/svelte/compiler.mjs:31232:5)
08:32:34.034    at compileSvelte2 (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:313:20)
08:32:34.034    at async Object.transform (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/dist/index.js:1460:27)
08:32:34.068    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
08:32:34.068    npm ERR! errno 1
08:32:34.072    npm ERR! league-page@1.2.6 build: `svelte-kit build`
08:32:34.072    npm ERR! Exit status 1
08:32:34.072    npm ERR!
08:32:34.072    npm ERR! Failed at the league-page@1.2.6 build script.
08:32:34.072    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
08:32:34.085    
08:32:34.086    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
08:32:34.086    npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2021-11-11T14_32_34_073Z-debug.log
08:32:34.101    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what version of Svelte you're using, but try installing v3.44.0:

```
npm install svelte@3.44.0
```

See here for a very similar issue:

> The latest version of SvelteKit now has a peerdependency on Svelte 3.44.0, which introduced the enableSourcemap option.

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2635#issuecomment-945996984